# Connecting Biopac MP36 to Simi Motion

Tags: matlab, interface, interactive, labview

I need to synchronize the biopac MP36 with the Simi Motion so that when we start / stop the recording of a device the other one does the same.

I know that there are an input trigger and an analogic output on the biopac and I thought that the signal for the Simi could be a light but I don't know how to create the global circuit of synchronization. And I thought that may be I need to use Matlab or LabVIEW to do this..

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MP36 manual](https://www.biopac.com/wp-content/uploads/MP36-MP45.pdf):

> A trigger device may be connected to the “Trigger” port on the back
>   panel.

There's more information on pages 3-4 on how to connect several MP36 together.

According to [Simi Motion's site](http://www.simi.com/en/products/movement-analysis/simi-motion-2d3d.html), for digital equipment:

> The majority of equipment can however be synchronised with a hardware
>   trigger, and the data can then be imported into Simi Motion.

However, if you are using a camera, maybe you will have to use a light to have a visual indication and then align your data with that marker (similar to the use of a clapperboard to sink image and audio on films) - check your product manual.

As the MP36 allows for a 5V analogue trigger, you should be able to use that line to feed a small light bulb, so when you press the trigger for the MP36 you get a visual indicator on the video.

The use of software (Labview or Matlab) is sometimes limited to the communication speed with each device and how well it can actually communicate with both at the "same time".

In my experience using labview to trigger several devices I normally prefer to use it to configure every device to expect a trigger and then use a single analogue signal to trigger them all externally (or a common *TRG signal through a GPIB net, for instance).

Comment: Yes I agree with you to use the analogue trigger of MP36 and create a light signal but I don't understand how the Simi motion understand that when there this indicator is capture by all video camera so the enregistrement of begin. Which parameter(s) must be changed or activated in the simi software?

Comment: I would start the video capture and then start the mp36, using the light to latter align the data. If it's really necessary to trigger the video acquisition at the same time you must look into the manual for the camera if it has an external trigger like the MP36.